# Npm Please try using this command again as root/administrator | error when install bootstrap jquery package

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

**Normally show this** :

> E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin>npm install bootstrap jquery --save
>   npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with
>   lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for
>   lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it! npm WARN
>   read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with
>   lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for
>   lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it! [
>   ......] - postinstall: info lifecycle jquery@3.2.1~postinstall:
>   jquery@3.2.1

It would install the package at 70%, then ( previous message ) then wait few minutes then show the following message :

E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin>npm install bootstrap jquery --save
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! path E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus\package.json'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus\package.json'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus\package.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sayed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-14T05_48_28_139Z-debug.log

E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin>

[See this image Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7BES.png)

> E:\NG4\19.Admin Panels\SupperAdmin>

Comment: You need to run with sudo

Comment: but my privius time don't fetch this problem, currently I'm use npm cli

Comment: It depends where you are installing. For this one, apparently, you need admin rights.

Comment: I'm Not Clear This Ans, Current I'm Use     
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 8.4.0
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related with this [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18287).

Run `npm i --no-optional` to overcome this issue. 
You could also downgrade the npm version you're using.